# Error in SQL syntax. 'WHERE post_id = '17'' at line 1

Tags: php, content-management-system

I have the following error:

> QUERY FAILED:You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE post_id = '17'' at line 1

This is my code:

```
$sql_query2 = "UPDATE posts SET post_title = '$post_title', post_category = '$post_category', post_tags = '$post_tags',  post_text = '$post_text',  post_image = '$post_image',  WHERE post_id = '$_POST[post_id]'";

$edit_post_query = mysqli_query($conn, $sql_query2);

   if(!$edit_post_query) {
    die("QUERY FAILED:" .mysqli_error($conn));
} else {

header("Location: posts.php");
```

What should I do to resolve that SQL syntax error?

Answer (score 1):

Remove the comma before the WHERE. Change

```
post_image = '$post_image',  WHERE post_id = '$_POST[post_id]'
```

to

```
post_image = '$post_image'  WHERE post_id = '$_POST[post_id]'
```

Comment: Oh -_- Thank you

Answer (score 0):

```
$sql_query2 = "UPDATE posts SET 
post_title = '".mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$post_title)."',
post_category = '".mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$post_category)."', 
post_tags = '".mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$post_tags),"',
post_text = '".mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$post_text)."',
post_image = '".mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$post_image)".' 
WHERE post_id ='".mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST[post_id])."' ";
```

Note: Usage mysqli_real_escape_string to protect from hackers.

Answer (score 0):

Or try this for $sql:

```
$sql_query2 = "UPDATE posts SET post_title = '.$post_title.', post_category = '.$post_category.', post_tags = '.$post_tags.',  post_text = '.$post_text.',  post_image = '.$post_image.',  WHERE post_id = '.$_POST[post_id].'";
```

or:

```
$sql_query2 = "UPDATE posts SET post_title = $post_title, post_category = $post_category, post_tags = $post_tags,  post_text = '$post_text',  post_image = $post_image,  WHERE post_id = '.$_POST[post_id].'";
```